# Using WebStorm 10, how do I include image/font files within my current project?

Tags: css, image, webstorm

Someone please help me before I take a golf club to my monitors.

I know this question will sound absurdly easy to most, but for the life of me I cannot include an image file (or any other outside file) in my WebStorm 10 project directory.  When I copy the image from my desktop to the WS environment, I get a complaint that the file "**is not included in the current project**" even though the destination folder shows the image file I just imported. Consequently, WS refuses to cooperate with my src references when trying to declare a background image in my stylesheet.

The JetBrains help guide conveniently skips this point and I seem to be the only person on the internet with this question. So please... treat my ignorance like a band-aid and make the sting a quick one. What am I missing?

If it makes any difference I included the bare bone CSS code I used to test the imported files, but as I said the problem isn't in the code- it's the inability to resolve the resource.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "UpperEastSide",
    src: url(\[project_name]\fonts\UpperEastSide.ttf);
}

body {
    background: url("\[project_name]\images\background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: when do you see the "is not included in the current project" error?

Comment: FYI: WebStorm resolves 'absolute' paths (starting from slash) relative to project root. Relative paths are resolved relative to current file. If you have a file [prj_root]/images/myImg.png, absolute reference should look like "/images/myImg.png"